# Set different time interval for each slide in vuetify carousels

Tags: vue.js, carousel, vuetify.js

I need to set a different time for each **v-carousel-item**, in Vuetify carousels.

Comment: you should provide some example code that you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to update the reactive property passed to the carousel and use the `@input` event to detect the slide as follows:

```
<!-- TEMPLATE -->
<v-carousel cycle :interval="interval" @input="onSlideChange">
    <v-carousel-item :key="1">First Item</v-carousel-item>
    <v-carousel-item :key="2">Second Item</v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

The event handler would update the property `interval` on each slide change:

```
const instance = new Vue({

    data() {
        // Use default interval of 1000ms
        return {
            interval: 1000
        }
    },

    methods: {

        onSlideChange(slideNumber) {
            if (slideNumber === 1) {
                this.interval === 500;
            } else if (slideNumber === 2) {
                this.interval === 800;
            } else {
                this.interval === 1000;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Ashok Consider accepting the answer as yes if it solves your problem.

Comment: only one issue when I embed Youtube video it keeps playing in the background even after slide change. Do you have any idea, how can we fix it?

Comment: @Ashok, that is the component's behavior! It must be using `display: none` or playing with `visibility/opacity` to create carousel effect. That slide component which has video is not really destroyed. You must hack around it when the slide is not active, remove video player from slide component. You can use the same event handler.